# extract the title of the url using scrapy,python

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy, Python. I need to extract the title of the urls and not the context. The below code extracts the contents along with the title.Kindly help on the above

Thank you in advance.

```
class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
         name = 'bg'
         start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com', 'https://scrapinghub.com/']

     def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('h2.entry-title'):
            yield {'title': title.css('a ::text').extract_first()}

        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'urltitle-%s.html' %page
        with open(filename,'wb') as f:
           f.write(response.body)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand correctly what do you mean by 'title', but if you need to extract `title` attribute of tag `a` you can extract it using appropriate selector `title.css('a::attr(title)')`

Comment: You are right and thanks much mizhgun. Also I tried using beautifulsoup for extracting and I wish to share it                                                                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml') 
        yield{
        "title" : soup.title.string }